# Phalcon DevTools Error while creating controller

Tags: php, phalcon

I am getting swift mail error when i run comman

> **phalcon controller --name=usercontrol --namespace=Ilm\Frontend\Controllers  --directory=apps/frontend/controller**
>
> Phalcon DevTools (1.3.2)
>
> Warning: require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/../tests/acceptance.conf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/config.php on line 69
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/../tests/acceptance.conf.php' (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/../lib:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/lib:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/../lib/classes:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/../lib:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/../tests/helpers:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/../tests/unit:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/../tests/acceptance:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/../tests/smoke:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/../tests/bug') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ilm/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/test-suite/config.php on line 69

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by just remove test-suite directory in swiftmail directory